# PayPal: Inconsistent guest payments

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, checkout

I am developing Express checkout with Merchant-SDK for classic API and I am experiencing some problems with guest paymens.

I have checked the **PayPal Account Optional** and I am manualy setting the **SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole** during setExpresCheckout.

However I am getting very inconsistent results (at some point I was able to use guest payment with PayPal Account Optional alone). Guest payment seems to work for only some states but they seem not to be always the same.

So I am wondering What else affects this? Where can I find some explanation?

Note: I am using shortened flow (useraction=commit) and setting the **LOCALCODE**. Right now I am also setting the **LANDINGPAGE=Billing** but It would be better for me to leave this on PayPal.

Comment: Found any solution for this issue I am facing the same issue

Comment: @RizwanAbbas Unfortunately no. PayPal simply decides what to show to the user. As far as I can tell it _is meant to be_ part of their security (¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯). I.e. if they decide for any reason  that they what the user to have an account then the user will have to authenticate. I have not found complete description of this logic thou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for integration level, PayPal Account Optional (set as 'on') and SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole are the only 2 steps for you to configure. Nothing else you should do. Such guest checkout issue for Express Checkout is mainly based on customer/buyer side, including the network environment, funding source status, etc., PayPal has its own risk detection mechanism to judge whether or not your customer is suitable for guest checkout. This risk detection mechanism is very complicated to find its rule.
But if your PayPal account is based on U.S., you can go to the link below to upgrade your PayPal account to the Pro account, and then you can integrate PayPal Direct Payment which can fully use guest checkout.
https://www.paypal-business.com/paypal-pro

Comment: Unfortunately that will not be the case (U.S. account). Our application will be used in multiple countries (multiple tennants) and I can not guarantee that they will use always the same account.